# I have two stored sting variable I need to concat into a different variable for an api get request

Tags: python

I use a location api to set my lat and long into variables. Which I am tying to pass into my location for my google API call.

I have tried different sequences of turning two string variables into one. (str(lat), str(lon)), (str(lat) + str(lon)), str(lat), str(lon), str(lat) + str(lon), and (str(lat, lon))

```
check_url = 'http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=3fea3b33a38ef7abd674c9e0515183be'
r = requests.get(check_url)
j = json.loads(r.text)
lat = j['latitude']
lon = j['longitude']
mylocation = (str(lat), str(lon))
```

I am trying to pass the lat and lon into the variable

```
LOCATION = 'mylocation'
```

for my api call.

It prints as '38.9208','-77.036'

But for my api call I need it to return as '38.9208,-77.036'

Comment: `','.join([str(lat), str(lon)])`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.join` to concatenate lat and lon:

```
import requests
import json

check_url = 'http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=3fea3b33a38ef7abd674c9e0515183be'
r = requests.get(check_url)
j = json.loads(r.text)
lat = j['latitude']
lon = j['longitude']

mylocation = (str(lat), str(lon))

print(','.join(mylocation))
```

Prints:

```
39.3752,21.8903
```